# AngularJs ChartJs tooltip z-index issue

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, core-ui

I  am using this template https://coreui.io/v1/demo/pro/AngularJS_Demo/#!/dashboard for my angular project. In that it includes `chart.js` and `angular-chart.js`. After good amount of googling, I am still not able to get the tooltip in the chart above all element presents.

[image]

In all the other product of `coreui` it shows properly. But I am not sure why it not showing here. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it seems they are using [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/) for the charts.

---

ChartJS should automatically find the right position for your tooltips, but since the chart area is *so small*, the tooltip would look cut-off when it has a top position too. Try increasing the area around the chart to give the tooltip some more space. Because all the other examples in your dashboard have larger charts/containers, the problem happens only in the small boxes.

When you want to have some more power over the tooltip, you can also switch to [HTML tooltips](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html?h=html) so *the tooltip will be added outside of the canvas*, and can be configured through CSS (like Z-index).

Comment: Sir, widening the area would solve the issue temporarily, but will not be a solution. In their other products for eg : https://coreui.io/angular/demo/#/dashboard , the tooltip comes well above. Even in plain html bootstrap link https://coreui.io/demo/#main.html it comes above.

Comment: Because it uses an HTML tooltip. Right click the chart, and check 'Inspect', you can see there is a `<div>` below `<canvas>`. Without HTML tooltip, it can not go outside of canvas.

Comment: Okay. There is a `CustomToolTip` options in `angular.chart.js`. But how to use it.?

Comment: You can either just check/copy the source code of your dashboard, or [check the documentation and an example of a custom tooltip here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html?h=html).

Comment: Finally, I copied the `custom-tooltip.js` contents and also the `chartjs-tooltip` css from the main css file. Finally got it. Thanks for your help sir.